# Writing an SQL function that can be accessed from a view and process user data based on a field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have a situation where I need to process user data in a view, to be presented to the user appropriately. I have a table with the following fields:

```
StartDate   DateTime
EndDate     DateTime
MoneySpent  Double
```

The complex part is that, the start date and end date could be 15 days apart, or 1 month apart or 2 months apart and there is no specific pattern. By pattern I mean that the dates are not always in a specified format like 1st April 2012 to 1st Jun 2012. For example this could have been 1st April 2012 to 31st May 2012.

I have a view which selects the 'Month' component from the start date and performs some aggregate functions on the MoneySpent Column. But for the above mentioned dates Month Component should ideally return 2 different months. As of now it considers all the money is spent in the month in the StartDate and the aggregate function understandably returns the wrong value. How do I write a function that will tackle my situation?

```
StartDate          EndDate          Spend
1 May 2012        1 Jun 2012         100
1 Jun 2012        30 Jun 2012        200
1 Jul 2012        31 Aug 2012        500
31 Aug 2012       29 Sep 2012        300
```

Consolidated View

```
Month      Spend
 May        100
 Jun        200
 Jul        250
 Aug        250
 Sep        300
```

Comment: If your columns are datetimes, what's all this concern about formats?

Comment: In my view, the column is not a full date, but it is a 'Month'. To give you an example, if the start date is 1st May 2013 and the end date is 31st May 2013 the view will have just 'May' in the month column and not the dates. 1st to 31st May should qualify as May, 1st May to 1st Jun should also qualify as May but 1st May to 30th June must classify as May and Jun. I want to achieve this.

Comment: "1st May to 1st Jun should also qualify as May"....why?

Comment: That is the requirement. I know it is a bit vague but our cutomers want to view their expenditures for each month. They dont want to see dates and they are using the data for charting purposes. The 12 months in the X axis and the values in Y. 1st May to 1st Jun is 31 days in May and 1 day in Jun(inclusive). Since it is more days in May, I need to put the value between 1st May and 1st Jun under May.

Comment: Could you show us some example data and the desired result? That might make it clearer what you are after.

Comment: @SebastianMeine: I have edited my question with an example

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, you seem to want to acheive the following:

2013-05-01 -> 2013-05-20 = MAY

2013-05-01 -> 2013-06-01 = MAY

2013-05-01 -> 2013-06-20 = MAY and JUNE

I wrote the following example script to acheive that.  just replace the variables with your DB fields.

```
            DECLARE @startDate AS DATETIME
            DECLARE @endDate AS DATETIME

            SELECT @startDate  = '2013-05-01'
            SELECT @endDate = '2013-06-02'

            SELECT 
                CASE WHEN MONTH(@startDate) <> MONTH(@endDate) THEN
                    CASE WHEN DAY(@endDate) > 1 THEN
                        DATENAME(MONTH, @startDate) + ' AND ' + DATENAME(MONTH, @endDate)
                    ELSE DATENAME(MONTH, @startDate)
                    END
                ELSE DATENAME(MONTH, @startDate)
                END AS theDate
```

Does that acheive what you were looking for?